# R: Error in converting character type to date type

Tags: r, date, datetime, lubridate

I have the following date column of class = "character" and length = 118

```
 [1] "01/10/2010" "01/11/2010" "01/12/2010" "01/01/2011" "01/02/2011" "01/03/2011" "01/04/2011" "01/05/2011" "01/06/2011"
 [10] "01/07/2011" "01/08/2011" "01/09/2011" "01/10/2011" "01/11/2011" "01/12/2011" "01/01/2012" "01/02/2012" "01/03/2012"
 [19] "01/04/2012" "01/05/2012" "01/06/2012" "01/07/2012" "01/08/2012" "01/09/2012" "01/10/2012" "01/11/2012" "01/12/2012"
 [28] "01/01/2013" "01/02/2013" "01/03/2013" "01/04/2013" "01/05/2013" "01/06/2013" "01/07/2013" "01/08/2013" "01/09/2013"
 [37] "01/10/2013" "01/11/2013" "01/12/2013" "01/01/2014" "01/02/2014" "01/03/2014" "01/04/2014" "01/05/2014" "01/06/2014"
 [46] "01/07/2014" "01/08/2014" "01/09/2014" "01/10/2014" "01/11/2014" "01/12/2014" "01/01/2015" "01/02/2015" "01/03/2015"
 [55] "01/04/2015" "01/05/2015" "01/06/2015" "01/07/2015" "01/08/2015" "01/09/2015" "01/10/2015" "01/11/2015" "01/12/2015"
 [64] "01/01/2016" "01/02/2016" "01/03/2016" "01/04/2016" "01/05/2016" "01/06/2016" "01/07/2016" "01/08/2016" "01/09/2016"
 [73] "01/10/2016" "01/11/2016" "01/12/2016" "01/01/2017" "01/02/2017" "01/03/2017" "01/04/2017" "01/05/2017" "01/06/2017"
 [82] "01/07/2017" "01/08/2017" "01/09/2017" "01/10/2017" "01/11/2017" "01/12/2017" "01/01/2018" "01/02/2018" "01/03/2018"
 [91] "01/04/2018" "01/05/2018" "01/06/2018" "01/07/2018" "01/08/2018" "01/09/2018" "01/10/2018" "01/11/2018" "01/12/2018"
[100] "01/01/2019" "01/02/2019" "01/03/2019" "01/04/2019" "01/05/2019" "01/06/2019" "01/07/2019" "01/08/2019" "01/09/2019"
[109] "01/10/2019" "01/11/2019" "01/12/2019" "01/01/2020" "01/02/2020" "01/03/2020" "01/04/2020" "01/05/2020" "01/06/2020"
[118] "01/07/2020"
```

I am trying to convert this column to a date format by doing

```
df$Date <- as_date(df$Date)
```

However, I'm getting the error

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, Date, value = numeric(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 118
```

How can I fix this?

**UPDATE**

When attempting

```
as.Date(df$Date, format="%d-%m-%Y")
```

the output is a NA for all rows

```
> as.Date(df$Date, format="%d-%m-%Y")
  [1] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [40] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
 [79] NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA
[118] NA
```

Comment: Where does the function `as_date` come from?

Comment: the lubridate package